# Не одинаковое отображение элементов на разных экранах

Tags: android, java

Добрый день! Если я верно понял, то с использованием единицы измерения dip элементы будут выглядеть одинаково на разных экранах. Однако, на деле разница есть:

Код в item_ad.xml:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="12dip"
        android:layout_height="12dip"
        android:layout_margin="6dip"
        android:id="@+id/marker_ad_image"
        android:src="@drawable/marker"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/item_ad_image"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/item_ad_image"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/item_ad_image" />
```

Который использует marker.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#96BF0D"/>
        <stroke android:width="1.5dip" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

В итоге:
huawei ascend d1, 4.5", 1280x720: (на нем приложение и тестировалось)

[image]

Samsung galaxy tab GT-P5110, 10.1", 1280x800

[image]

Речь о не правильном отображении маркера (ну и шрифта). Как быть в такой ситуации?

Comment: http://startandroid.ru/ru/materialy/pamjatka/40-edinitsy-izmerenija-chem-otlichaetsja-dp-dip-ot-px-screen-density
вот по теме статья

Comment: iksuy, тот материал я читал и он мало чем помог. По сути там говорится "используйте dip и будет вам счастье". Однако, в текущем примере он и используется и даже разрешение почти одинаковое, разный только физический размер. Однако dip не помог, вот я и прошу знатоков поделиться советом...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут выход один, выносить размер `android:width="1.5dip"` в ресурсы, в разные типы экранов и, соответственно,  значения должны быть разными.

Попробуйте создать папку `res/values-normal` и в ней создать файлик с размерами для телефона, а в `res/values-xlarge` создать файлик с размерами для планшета.

Играть явно нужно с этими параметрами (компоновкой для разных типов экранов)

Comment: А можно поменять xml файл при первом запуске? Поменять размеры в единицах px опираясь на ширину экрана было бы хорошо. Тогда точно выглядело бы одинаково, а не похоже..

Comment: @Saint не советую так делать, это костыль

Answer (score 1):

Вы сравниваете телефон и планшет. Для планшета создаются свои файлы разметки в папках layout-sw720dp и layout-sw600dp